# Writing Spark dataframe to DynamoDB table using Python

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

How I can write Spark dataframe to DynamoDB using  emr-dynamodb-connector and Python?
I can't find how I can create new JobConf with pyspark.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?